# SQL Query to calculate remaining running balances based on a given conditions

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stock transaction table like this:

```
StockID Item  TransDate   TranType  BatchNo Qty Price 
10001   ABC   01-Apr-2012   IN     71001000 200  750.0
10002   ABC   02-Apr-2012   OUT             100       
10003   ABC   03-Apr-2012   IN     71001001  50  700.0
10004   ABC   04-Apr-2012   IN     71001002  75  800.0
10005   ABC   10-Apr-2012   OUT             125       
10006   XYZ   05-Apr-2012   IN     71001003 150  350.0
10007   XYZ   05-Apr-2012   OUT             120       
10008   XYZ   15-Apr-2012   OUT              10       
10009   XYZ   20-Apr-2012   IN     71001004  90  340.0
10010   PQR   06-Apr-2012   IN     71001005  50  510.0
10011   PQR   15-Apr-2012   IN     71001006  60  505.0
10012   MNO   01-Apr-2012   IN     71001007  76  410.0
10013   MNO   11-Apr-2012   OUT              76
```

Each of my IN transactions has price associated to it and a batch number (lot number). Now I would like to calculate the remaining quantity by First In First Out (FIFO) rule, meaning the first in should be adjusted with first out. After adjusting the quantities the remaining balances are to be calculated against each IN transaction for the same item as shown below:

```
StockID Item  TransDate   TranType  BatchNo Qty Price  RemainingQty
10001   ABC   01-Apr-2012   IN     71001000 200  750.0    0        
10002   ABC   02-Apr-2012   OUT             100             
10003   ABC   03-Apr-2012   IN     71001001  50  700.0   25        
10004   ABC   04-Apr-2012   IN     71001002  75  800.0   75        
10005   ABC   10-Apr-2012   OUT             125             
10006   XYZ   05-Apr-2012   IN     71001003 150  350.0   20        
10007   XYZ   05-Apr-2012   OUT             120             
10008   XYZ   15-Apr-2012   OUT              10             
10009   XYZ   20-Apr-2012   IN     71001004  90  340.0   90        
10010   PQR   06-Apr-2012   IN     71001005  50  510.0   50        
10011   PQR   15-Apr-2012   IN     71001006  60  505.0   60        
10012   MNO   01-Apr-2012   IN     71001007  76  410.0   0         
10013   MNO   11-Apr-2012   OUT              76
```

As we can see from the above table for item ABC, after adjusting (125 + 100) OUT qty against the IN qty (100 + 50 + 75) using FIFO the quantity remaining for the batch 71001000 is 0, 71001001 is 25 and for batch 71001002 is 75. From the remaining quantity the value can be derived.

Please help me to achieve this using any of the methods (either cursor based or CTE or JOINS, etc)
Thanks in advance for the help.

One of the users of StockOverflow suggested this answer:

```
SELECT 10001   as stockid,'ABC' as item,'01-Apr-2012' as transdate,'IN' as trantype,     71001000 as batchno, 200 as qty,  750.0  as price INTO #sample
UNION ALL SELECT 10002   ,'ABC','02-Apr-2012','OUT', NULL            ,100,NULL        
UNION ALL SELECT 10003   ,'ABC','03-Apr-2012','IN',     71001001,  50 , 700.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10004   ,'ABC','04-Apr-2012','IN',     71001002,  75 , 800.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10005   ,'ABC','10-Apr-2012','OUT',     NULL        ,125,NULL        
UNION ALL SELECT 10006   ,'XYZ','05-Apr-2012','IN',     71001003, 150 , 350.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10007   ,'XYZ','05-Apr-2012','OUT',      NULL      , 120    ,NULL    
UNION ALL SELECT 10008   ,'XYZ','15-Apr-2012','OUT',       NULL     ,  10        ,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 10009   ,'XYZ','20-Apr-2012','IN',     71001004,  90 , 340.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10010   ,'PQR','06-Apr-2012','IN',     71001005,  50 , 510.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10011   ,'PQR','15-Apr-2012','IN',     71001006,  60 , 505.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10012   ,'MNO','01-Apr-2012','IN',     71001007,  76 , 410.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10013   ,'MNO','11-Apr-2012','OUT',    NULL    ,76 ,NULL


;WITH remaining AS
(
    SELECT *,
           CASE 
                WHEN trantype = 'IN' THEN 1
                ELSE -1
           END * qty AS stock_shift,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY transdate) AS row,
           CASE 
                WHEN trantype = 'OUT' THEN NULL
                ELSE ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY item, CASE WHEN trantype = 'IN' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY transdate)
           END AS in_row,
           SUM(CASE WHEN trantype = 'OUT' THEN qty END) OVER(PARTITION BY item) AS total_out
    FROM   #sample
)
,remaining2 AS
(
    SELECT r1.item,
           r1.stockid,
           MAX(r1.transdate) AS transdate,
           MAX(r1.trantype) AS trantype,
           MAX(r1.batchno) AS batchno,
           MAX(r1.qty) AS qty,
           MAX(r1.price) AS price,
           MAX(r1.total_out) AS total_out,
           MAX(r1.in_row) AS in_row,
           CASE 
                WHEN MAX(r1.trantype) = 'OUT' THEN NULL
                WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN r1.trantype = 'IN' THEN r2.qty ELSE 0 END) - MAX(r1.total_out) < 0 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN r1.trantype = 'IN' THEN r2.qty ELSE 0 END) 
                     - MAX(r1.total_out)
                ELSE 0
           END AS running_in
    FROM   remaining r1
           LEFT OUTER JOIN remaining r2
                ON  r2.row <= r1.row
                AND r2.item = r1.item
    GROUP BY
           r1.item,
           r1.stockid
)
SELECT r2.item,
       r2.stockid,
       MAX(r2.transdate) AS transdate,
       MAX(r2.trantype) AS trantype,
       MAX(r2.batchno) AS batchno,
       MAX(r2.qty) AS qty,
       MAX(r2.price) AS price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN r2.trantype = 'OUT' THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(r2.qty + r3.running_in, 0) END) AS remaining_stock
FROM   remaining2 r2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN remaining2 r3
            ON  r2.in_row - 1 = r3.in_row
            AND r2.item = r3.item
GROUP BY
       r2.item,
       r2.stockid
```

This sql is having a problem and the result is attached here[image: Query Result] The records for which the value are not matching are indicated in yellow color. Kindly help to solve the problem.

Comment: The obvious question to ask is why don't you have a BatchNo assigned to the OUT records? It would make things much easier to solve your problem. Your question clearly tells of the relationship, but your table definition does not reflect this.

Comment: Hi @Brad the batch number is just a transaction number created to identify a lot. However, all the lots are physically mixed together and issued. But for accounting purposes the result is required.

Comment: @Nagesh I've modified my original answer below which works for your sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick?

```
SELECT 10001   as stockid,'ABC' as item,'01-Apr-2012' as transdate,'IN' as trantype,     71001000 as batchno, 200 as qty,  750.0  as price INTO #sample
UNION ALL SELECT 10002   ,'ABC','02-Apr-2012','OUT', NULL            ,100,NULL        
UNION ALL SELECT 10003   ,'ABC','03-Apr-2012','IN',     71001001,  50 , 700.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10004   ,'ABC','04-Apr-2012','IN',     71001002,  75 , 800.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10005   ,'ABC','10-Apr-2012','OUT',     NULL        ,125,NULL        
UNION ALL SELECT 10006   ,'XYZ','05-Apr-2012','IN',     71001003, 150 , 350.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10007   ,'XYZ','05-Apr-2012','OUT',      NULL      , 120    ,NULL    
UNION ALL SELECT 10008   ,'XYZ','15-Apr-2012','OUT',       NULL     ,  10        ,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 10009   ,'XYZ','20-Apr-2012','IN',     71001004,  90 , 340.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10010   ,'PQR','06-Apr-2012','IN',     71001005,  50 , 510.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10011   ,'PQR','15-Apr-2012','IN',     71001006,  60 , 505.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10012   ,'MNO','01-Apr-2012','IN',     71001007,  76 , 410.0 
UNION ALL SELECT 10013,'MNO','11-Apr-2012','OUT',          NULL    ,76 ,NULL

;with remaining_stock as
( 
SELECT * 
,CASE WHEN trantype = 'IN' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END * qty AS stock_shift
,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY transdate) as row
,CASE WHEN trantype = 'OUT' THEN NULL ELSE
row_number()OVER (PARTITION BY item,CASE WHEN trantype = 'IN' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY transdate) END as in_row
,CASE WHEN trantype = 'IN' THEN NULL ELSE
row_number()OVER (PARTITION BY item,CASE WHEN trantype = 'OUT' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY transdate) END as out_row
,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN trantype = 'OUT' THEN qty END) OVER (PARTITION BY item),0) AS total_out
,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN trantype = 'IN' THEN qty END) OVER (PARTITION BY item),0) AS total_in
FROM #sample
)
,remaining_stock2 AS
(
SELECT 
r1.item
,r1.stockid
,MAX(r1.transdate) as transdate
,MAX(r1.trantype) as trantype
,MAX(r1.batchno) as batchno
,MAX(r1.qty) as qty
,MAX(r1.price) as price
,MAX(r1.total_in) as total_in
,MAX(r1.total_out) as total_out
,SUM(r2.qty) as running_in
FROM remaining_stock r1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN remaining_stock r2 on r2.in_row <= r1.in_row
                    AND r2.item = r1.item       
GROUP BY
r1.item
,r1.stockid 
)
SELECT
item
,stockid
,transdate
,trantype
,batchno
,qty
,price
,CASE WHEN  trantype = 'OUT' THEN NULL
        WHEN total_out >= running_in THEN 0 
        WHEN (running_in - total_out) < qty THEN (running_in - total_out)
        WHEN (running_in - total_out) >= qty THEN qty 
        END as remaining_stocks
FROM remaining_stock2
```

Comment: Dear @Davin, thanks for the answer and you are the one who gave the first solution. All credits to you. Let me check and confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear to me on how the FIFO logic is to be applied. I'm going to assume that you want to associate each `IN` record against the next `OUT` record if one exists. To achieve this you need to join the table on itself like the following

```
select
    t1.BatchNo,
    isnull(t1.Qty,0)  as 'IN Qty',
    isnull(t2.Qty,0)  as 'OUT Qty',
    isnull(t1.Qty,0) - isnull(t2.Qty,0) as 'Remaining Qty'
from 
    tbl_test t1
left join tbl_test t2
    on t2.StockID = (t1.StockID + 1)
    and t2.TranType = 'OUT'
where
    t1.TranType = 'IN'
```

The results will show you the following for the first 5 records for `ABC` from your question.

> ```
> BatchNo  | IN Qty | OUT Qty | Remaining Qty
> 71001000 | 200    | 100     | 100
> 71001001 | 50     | 0       | 50
> 71001002 | 75     | 125     | -50
> ```

The left join works on the assumption that the StockID for each IN record is always one less number than the associated OUT record. I personally think your data model needs improving.

- OUT records should have a BatchNo assigned or a reference to the
  StockID of the associated IN record
- add a timestamp field for sequential ordering
- add a DateTime field for handling IN/OUT occuring on same day

Comment: Hi @Brad, timestamp and Datetime exist in the data model and they have not shown here for simplicity. But BatchNo reference doesn't exist and this is the way the data model is designed. Kindly help to achieve the required result.

Comment: If you can clarify the logic a bit more, I can try to take my answer further. I don't understand why the first record in your desired results has `RemainingQty = 0` when the IN = 200 and OUT = 100 for BatchNo 71001000. I would have expected `RemainingQty = 100`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Brad. For item ABC there are 5 transactions - 3 INs and 2 OUTs. The net quantity inflow from all IN is 325 and net outflow from OUTs is 225 and the net remaining is 100. This 100 qty to be allocated to each batches based on FIFO. Since 200 Qty is the first IN Transaction it is annulled out.

Comment: OK, so the total sum quantity for ABC = 100 in the table. I can see why BatchNo 71001000 would display `zero` (i.e. total sum of 100 - batch IN-OUT of 100), but I don't get why BatchNo 71001001 would then display `25`? because there is no more remaining quantity left to allocate

Comment: For batch 71001000 the qty is 200 and the next transaction is OUT with qty 100 and hence the balance is 100. Subsequent to this there are two IN transactions with 50 and 75 qty. So the total stock qty is (100+50+75) = 225. The next transaction after these two INs is the OUT with 125 qty. Now this 125 has to be adjusted using FIFO. Therefore 100 of 125 has been adjusted against the remaining 100 qty for the batch 71001000. The remaining 25 has been adjusted against batch 71001001 since it is the very next IN transaction. Hope my explanation is sufficient.